# Cannot associate Simple Products in a Configurable

Tags: magento

I did an upgrade from 1.4.2 to 1.5.0 and realized that the product association in a Configurable product didn't work. After hours of rollbacks and testing I haven't found a solution. Even though I did a rollback to the previous version and database I couldn't get it back on track. I've tried to uninstall all extensions we have installed lately with the same result. This site is more or less based on Configurables so we are sort of stuck...

I've found some details though;

- Simple products created *before* the upgrade can be associated to a new Configurable product and existing ones.
- Simple products made *after* the upgrade can’t be associated to *any* Configurable product.
- When I create a new Configurable and make an association with the quick tool the new Simple product is created, but there's no insert to the database table catalog_product_relation for example.

It seems that the Adminhtml is broken by something. I have no lead any longer so please fill in with suggestions what to look for.

Comment: When you say that the association is broken, can you be more specific? Does the interface report success and then not save any data? Are there errors reported? Do you have logging turned on, and have you checked those logs?

Comment: When the _Quick simple product creation_ is used the _Super product attributes configuration_ list is updated, but no Simple product is listed below. If we then save and go back to the main products list the Simple products are there. When we re-open the Configurable product, all associated lists are empty.
All Simple products that are created now can be viewed as simple products, but none of them can be used in a Configurable.
Unfortunately, neither system nor exception log yields.

Comment: I've posted a video clip to show the behaviour: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPuCIyCDU3M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found it, hours later. :)
I went through the server side code, the client js-scripts and came to the conclusion that even though the server side is updated, the js-scripts are the same. And they didn't get the data back I expected when the association was added.
It all drilled down to the settings of the attribute that the configurable option was based upon (it seems the DB lookup is changed and the attribute affected the result). I found that the result sets from the db differed when a simple product was created before the upgrade, compared to a simple product created after the upgrade.
I think 1.5 is alot more picky when it comes to the settings as this attribute has been used for more then 500 products with no problem.

I changed the attribute to be valid for all product types and not mandatory. Now we can create Configurables again!

Comment: i found i had to make sure the simples i wanted all had values for the attribute fields selected for that configurable for them to show up in the search form

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, your **attributes set** must be applicable to all product types, or almost `Simple Product` and `Configurable Product`.

[image: Configuration Screenshoot]

Answer (score 1):

I verified all the above with no success however I did find one more issue that solved my problem: I had created an attribute without setting a default value. I had added about 270 products but only 20 had this attribute set. Once I went back in and created a default option like "N/A" and then reset all the attributes for these products - the configurable product started working. It was like having that attribute that didn't have any default and some products didn't have it set - was breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

i have get into this problem the thing you need to do inside the product and the associated product is the following : 
go to 
websites >> and check all the stores your want your product appear into it.