# matrix component association issue

Tags: magento

Background:
     I have a running magnto application. I have created a new module inside app/code/locale. Inside this folder I have controller called SyncController.
Inside this controller I am calling a method in model Like below;

```
<?php
class Connect_SyncController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action  {

    function IndexAction() {
    }

    function ProductAction()  {
        Mage::getModel('connect/product')->sync();
    }

}
?>
```

Product action in model receives a json input and the json input will contain matrix item and matrix component item.

Problem:

So for it was working fine. Whenever I sent matrix item and component items, those all were added and associated properly. Suddenly there is an problem in associating components to its matrix item. Matrix items and components are being saved successfully no issues with that. But, components are not associating to its parent. Even there is no error throwing. Surprise is, once in a while it works. 
I referred below suggestion also;

[Cannot associate Simple Products in a Configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156021/cannot-associate-simple-products-in-a-configurable)

But there is no up gradation or change in configuration exists in recent past.

Can anyone suggest what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase max_input_time from php.ini. And restart the apache server.

Comment: Problem in live server

Comment: Talk to your server manager or hosting provider. They will do that.

Comment: Till few months back it was working fine. Even the previous request contain 20 products sometimes, that time it was working fine. But now just for 2 or 3 products it is not working, do you think, it is related to max_input_time?

Comment: It could be that issue. Just give a try.